# call mvc razor view from javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, data-binding

is it possible to call another mvc razor view from the main view via javascript function or we should always use the action controller ?
in case, there is some parameters to send to the new view, how to perform that with javasript function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never call a View directly from Javascript.

You call a controller (with parameters if needed) and the controller then processes the data and returns a View.

The View is always the result of a Controller and never called straight from any external front end code. The View of a Controller Action can however use multiple Partial Views to accomplish the end result.

Comment: in my case, i have a main view contains a gridpanel. when i click one element of the grid panel, i want to create a popup window to show some details about the selected element. why should i get back to the server and again the client side ??

Comment: You can either open a separate page which would be a separate Action that you request from the server or you could have the extra data hidden in a div that you display when the user clicks the link

Comment: Or use a lightbox that shows your extra data: http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/?u=9

Comment: elements showed in the grid panel with few properties when clicked they will be showed in new window with some other properties so i cant use lightbox

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use Partial Views. For example as JensB said, you never call a view, you call a controller.

Javascript

```
function GetPartialView(parameter){    
    var url = "@Url.Action("PartialView", "Controller", new { parameter= "-parameter" })";
    url = url.replace("-parameter", parameter);
    //HTML element to load the partial view 
    $("#DivElement").load(url);
}
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult PartialView()
    {
        //Code you need to return to the partial view...
        return PartialView("partialview");
    }
```

So after the javascript is called, you are sending a call to the controller and the controller make it's work to send the specific view you specified.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you Jorge, can i use partial view to create popup windows ?

Comment: Well If you can use a Jquery plugin that handle popup and html content, I could imagine it's posible. Maybe when a plugin handle callbacks, after showing the callback you can load your partialview into the modal (depends on the modal of course)